# Python can't make variable from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables

From a file I have an ID in the first column, then the person's name in the second column of the text and the IDs/usernames are separated by lines. I'm trying to make a variable of the second column of the file, the one next to the correct ID however when I attempt this, I get an error stating that the local variable 'realName' referenced before assignment. I have no global variables with in my code as well. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
fileOpen=("details.txt","r")
ID=input("What is your ID?")
for line in fileOpen:
    details=line.strip().split(",")
    if ID==details[0]:#id will always match something inside the file
        realName=details[1] 
        break
print("Hi, {0}".format(realName))
```

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Without being able to reproduce the problem, we can only guess. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: If none of the lines match the condition `name == details[0]`, you never set `realName`, so you'll get that error.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of the if statement isn't running. Making a variable open("filename", "r") does not make that variable a string. It is simply a pointer to a class. Instead, you should do:

```py
fileOpen=("details.txt","r")
ID=input("What is your ID?")
for line in fileOpen.read(): # You need to add the .read() method to make the fileopen variable a string
    details=line.strip().split(",")
    if ID==details[0]: # id will always match something inside the file
        realName=details[1] 
        break
print("Hi, {0}".format(realName))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if `name` doesn't match the first field of any of the lines, since you only set `realName` when you find a match. You can provide a default when this happens using an `else:` clause:

```
def userMenu(name):
    fileOpen=("details.txt","r")
    for line in fileOpen:
        details=line.strip().split(",")
        if name==details[0]:
            realName=details[1] 
            break
    else:
        realName = "Unknown user"
    print("hi {0}".format(realName))
```

Comment: Even when entering 100% correct username's, I get unknown user. Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you add a print statement to the loop so you can see what `details[0]` is.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file contents?

Comment: Is there a space after the comma in the file?

Comment: I added a 'print("user found' after the if statement to see if it does match, and it will print user found confirming that the log in is correct however the name is still unknown user in the print statement @Barmar

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ab4da4f8527cea030d009dd7e3dc3ca8 -screenshot of the program in action

Comment: Where is `user found`?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/478254d6dd851b2301979b61643b7eae - that is the document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167767/discussion-between-sean-and-barmar).